# How to make surrounding average and basic calculations based on numpy neighboring cells

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, conv-neural-network

I have a 10 by 10 numpy array. For every cell in the array (as depicted in the snapshot below), I wanted to make calculations based on left, right, top, and bottom neighboring cells, as well as a weighted moving average window based on the surrounding grid cells around each cell in the numpy array (based on its i and j index). I was not sure how to account for grid cells that are located at the edges (boundaries and corners, as they only have a partial of the window kernel around them). Is there any pythonic way to perform these types of tasks? For the weighted_moving_average, the 8 immediate surrounding cells should have a 70% (stronger) whereas the not_immediate sorounding cells (16) should have 30% weights (weaker).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

noisy_data = [[0.0467251, 0.0529133, 0.0775945, 0.0640082, 0.0439774, 0.0915829,
        0.0547699, 0.0826791, 0.0883616, 0.0977739],
       [0.0875183, 0.0790368, 0.101146 , 0.0777582, 0.104289 , 0.0775479,
        0.156569 , 0.0999909, 0.0905242, 0.161871 ],
       [0.1427   , 0.1211   , 0.15661  , 0.113337 , 0.135986 , 0.1384   ,
        0.181515 , 0.159102 , 0.200004 , 0.187535 ],
       [0.163381 , 0.186425 , 0.174798 , 0.14191  , 0.1514   , 0.166044 ,
        0.199063 , 0.146319 , 0.173303 , 0.144067 ],
       [0.182485 , 0.16901  , 0.11     , 0.127162 , 0.0858656, 0.1564   ,
        0.161187 , 0.0588985, 0.110706 , 0.0560944],
       [0.103804 , 0.109948 , 0.0707144, 0.0493536, 0.0471329, 0.0708205,
        0.048201 , 0.0487304, 0.069967 , 0.0947939],
       [0.0382397, 0.0918   , 0.101197 , 0.102453 , 0.135943 , 0.0867575,
        0.123071 , 0.0970329, 0.099906 , 0.101536 ],
       [0.113361 , 0.167597 , 0.141526 , 0.0792396, 0.118    , 0.065764 ,
        0.0915817, 0.1183   , 0.149376 , 0.118608 ],
       [0.10647  , 0.1566   , 0.1303   , 0.139754 , 0.174465 , 0.148458 ,
        0.187625 , 0.132805 , 0.171687 , 0.158161 ],
       [0.15319  , 0.174204 , 0.161628 , 0.127377 , 0.173368 , 0.145292 ,
        0.208068 , 0.168076 , 0.14961  , 0.124334 ]]

noisy_data = np.array(noisy_data).reshape(10, 10)

plt.imshow(noisy_data, cmap ="jet")
plt.colorbar()


new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['left_neighboring_index') = [(np.abs(noisy_data[i-1] -noisy_data[i]))/(noisy_data[i-1) +        noisy_data[i])  for i in noisy_data]

new_df['right_neighboring_index') = [(np.abs(noisy_data[i+1] -noisy_data[i]))/(noisy_data[i+1) +  noisy_data[i])  for i in noisy_data]

new_df['bottom_neighboring_index') = [(np.abs(noisy_data[j-1] -noisy_data[j]))/(noisy_data[j-1) + noisy_data[j])  for i in noisy_data]

new_df['top_neighboring_index') = [(np.abs(noisy_data[j+1] -noisy_data[j]))/(noisy_data[j+1) + noisy_data[j])  for i in noisy_data]

new_df['weighted_moving_average_size_20_(8+12)') = ...?
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is what is known as a convolution. In a convolution on a matrix, a kernel (smaller matrix) is swept across the matrix.

I can try to explain this but I rather suggest you watch this [excellent video](https://youtu.be/KuXjwB4LzSA?t=512) by 3blue1brown on the topic which gives you a good visual understanding of convolutions.

For example for giving a 70% weight for the 8 surrounding cells and 30% for 12 around those, you could use a kernel like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

np.random.seed(3141)
A = np.random.uniform(size=(10,10))

k = np.array([
    [.3, .3, .3, .3, .3],
    [.3, .7, .7, .7, .3],
    [.3, .7, .0, .7, .3],
    [.3, .7, .7, .7, .3],
    [.3, .3, .3, .3, .3]
])

# normalize k so it sums up to 1
k /= k.sum() 

Aprime = convolve2d(A, k, mode='full', boundary='fill')
```

This will result in the following image

[image: convolution2D]

There are several ways to deal with boundary cells (aslo explained in the video I think). For this you can use the `boundary` argument in the `convolve2D` function (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)).

Comment: @Jella Westra For some reasons, when I run your code, the Aprime is a 14, 14 size ! not a 10 by 10 as original A array. And my second question is that is every value in the Aprime "weighted average" of the surrounding points? And my other question is does your method work for a 3d numpy array too? In other words, when the noisy_data is 3d and kernel is 3d as well, and its size is k_3d = (3, 5, 5)? (with the same weighted average strategy).

Comment: @2023_resolution 1 To get the same shape output (10,10) you can use the `mode='same'` instead of `mode='full'` parameter of `convolve2d`. Like I said, also have a look at the `boundary` parameter. 2 Yes the values in Aprime represent the weighted averages of A. So for instance if you take `Aprime[5,5]` (after using `mode='same'`) this represents the weighted average around `A[5,5]`. 3 You can use this for higher dimensions as well. In this case instead of `convolve2d` use `scipy.signal.convolve` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do operation similar to 2D convolution but not exactly convolution. In convolution, we do multiply with a kernel and then sum the resulting value and place it in each cell. You want the average of the product to be placed in the cell instead.

To handle the border and corner cells, we can pad the array. Here I have implemented 'SAME' padding meaning the output will be of same shape as that of input array `img`.

```
def surr_avg(img, kernel):
    kernel_shape = kernel.shape
    # Calculate padding width (f -1)//2
    p = (kernel_shape[0] - 1)//2
    pad_img = np.pad(img, pad_width=p)
    # get the sliding window view of the image.
    sub_matrices = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(pad_img , kernel_shape)
    # Multiply kernel with each window of img using einsum.
    conv = np.einsum('kl,ijkl->ijkl',kernel,sub_matrices)
    # find the reduced mean along the last two axis.
    return conv.mean(axis=(-1,-2))
```

For **simple average**:

```
k = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [1,0,1], 
              [1,1,1]])
avg = surr_avg(a, k)
```

For **weighted average**, we need to give the corresponding kernel. I am directly taking the weighted kernel from [Jelle Westra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75181644/5462372)

```
wk = np.array([
    [.3, .3, .3, .3, .3],
    [.3, .7, .7, .7, .3],
    [.3, .7, .0, .7, .3],
    [.3, .7, .7, .7, .3],
    [.3, .3, .3, .3, .3]
])
wk /= wk.sum()
wght_avg = surr_avg(a, wk)
```

Comment: does your method work for a 3d numpy array too? In other words, when the noisy_data is 3d and kernel is 3d as well, and its size is k_3d = (3, 5, 5)? (with the same weighted average strategy) and my second question is regarding the border points. I tested it on the noisy_data and the border points don't seem to follow any surrounding averaging nor they are the same as input data!